# Social sharing buttons speed up

Tags: javascript, facebook, wordpress

My aim is to speed up page loading time with social sharing.

I am thinking of writing a script that downloads every day the js for facebook twitter ... etc and adds all to a minified single js, that I can include in my page. (background cronjob)

This way my page would not have to download from multiple servers, js can be included in one file, and since it is done every day remote script timeout would not be an issue.

As a theory it is ok, I just thought I would ask if anybody has done this before, and if there are any drawbacks I have not thought of yet. Alternatively, is there a wp plugin that does this?

Comment: Static JavaScript assets are generally cached.

Comment: you mean by the browser? I can overcome that by varying the name of the js, or adding short expiry time in htaccess.

Comment: If you're interested in speeding things up, you should *want* the files to be cached.

Comment: Are you using a caching plugin?

Comment: @TomásCot not so far. Can you suggest any?

Comment: @Sesertin, yes, W3 Total Cache. It will do more for performance that what you are trying to acomplish now. Also, you may find [this interesting](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/add-lazy-loading-social-sharing-buttons-to-your-wordpress-blog--wp-26613)

Comment: "Alternatively, is there a wp plugin that does this?" FYI, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to load those JS assets asynchronously - or "lazy load" - from the social sharing services themselves and have them active on scroll or hover.

See https://github.com/tmort/Socialite and http://wordpress.org/plugins/wpsocialite/

Comment: Yes, I have already gave some thoughts to that, but considering SEO and that google somehow extracts social media data, I am not sure if it can still access social metrics, if I activate the buttons on scroll or hover. Have you possibly got any experience with that?

Comment: "...but considering SEO and that google somehow extracts social media data..." Where did you hear this from?

Comment: http://moz.com/search-ranking-factors take a look at correlation data with google +1s (leading) likes, etc. There is also a similar chart for 2014 but I could not find that. Am I missing something?